# Lots of files .CAB under C:\Windows\System32\Spool

Tags: windows, printing, system, printers, spooler

I work for a company as a helpdesk technician. Today, an employee brought his computer to me with the described issue. I discovered 20GB of files that I've tried to delete, but after a few seconds, the same issue occurred again!

I've searched the web but didn't find anything about this issue. Do you have any advice to solve it?

I've tried restarting the print spooler service, disconnecting all printers, and following this guide:

Open the Registry Editor by running regedit.exe. Browse to the following registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print. Add a REG_DWORD value named DisableWERLogging and set this value to 0x1 (hexadecimal). Restart the Print Spooler service.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you'd better ask this on superuser, as SO is for programming questions